# how to prevent the next authentication session refresh when I close the browser, then reopen it and access the application again

Tags: next-auth

I am working with next-auth. I have set the `maxAge` property in session to 30 days, but there is a problem that when I close the browser and open it again, then access the application the time expires of the session is refreshed again. It seems to add 30 days from the moment I reopen the browser and access my application.

How can I prevent this session from refreshing, I have tried `refetchWhenOffline={false}` property doesn't work, and `refetchOnWindowFocus={false}` property. It only works when I focus on another tab and refocus the app (session won't be refreshed), but it doesn't work when I closed the browser and reopened it then accessed the app again.